# advice re:ground connections inside a metal box

Tags: wiring

When installing two switches in a double gang metal box, I mistakenly followed the directions for doing this in a plastic box. So I bundled the five ground wires with a marette, but failed to make a connection via pig tail to the metal box. Is this OK to leave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code requires the metal box to be grounded. I would ask if the yokes for the switches contact the box, this can be a compliant ground in some jurisdictions.

Answer (score 3):

I just did that today.  The box's ground screw hole wasn't on a dome, and it was mounted on a metal surface, so I couldn't use it without bottoming out.  Just grounded to the receptacle, which is hard flush against the box, so done.  Switches don't need to be hard flush; they are allowed to ground via the screw threads even if the switch is not hard flush.

Answer (score 0):

That would not normally be accepted in the jurisdictions I have worked. I was given some grace and allowed to do that with designated self-grounding switches where I failed to notice that an apprentice didn't put a ground screw in a concrete embedded box.